# iPhone:How to use UIGraphicsPushContext

Tags: iphone, cgcontextref

I am making a iPhone app in which a user draw on iPhone screen using his finger

On ViewController1  i am showing  a view subclassed from another UIView class 
I store all touches moved points in an array

On this view user draws using his finger

user then navigates on another view ViewController2

Then on ViewController3 i want to redraw that points on that view on an image but this time i get error  invalid context 0 X 0

I think i need to use  UIGraphicsPushContext

But i do not know how to use that

Can anyone suggest me what is the way to solve this problem

Or is there any other way to solve this problem

Comment: Dinesh Kaushik and @Mohit Gupta: this post is more valuable to all of us when all of the relevant details of the problem are added to the question, and the resolution of the problem is stated as an answer and accepted.  Please don't use the comments to add important information: edit the question and answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your points in NSUserDefaults whatever you find in previous class and in the next class you can get these points..AS for As I understand that your requirement.

Comment: i have these points in a nsmutable array  but when i want to redraw them again on that subclassed uiview then i get error invalid context 0X0

Comment: add your screen shot to understand problem.I am not getting what u want exactly.

Comment: if you want to same image that you draw in previous class then you can

Comment: you can store this image in document directory and fetch where you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your help
Just give me some time i will explain my problem properly with screen shots

Comment: http://iphoneapp-dev.blogspot.com by this link you can download sample code of DrawImageExample that may be helpful in this example whatever you draw by your finger will be store on photo library.so you can store your image in document directory and fetch in another class

Comment: Yes i solved my problem
Using the Alternative way of Creating an image using UIgraphicsgetimagefrom current context  
and then using that image in any viewcontroller